# Proof that $(a^m+b^m)^{n}= (a^n+b^n)^m\implies m=n$

Tags: inequality

Edit: I goofed up. Need to show that If $$(a^m+b^m)^{n}= (a^n+b^n)^m$$ then $m=n$ where $a,b$ are fixed positive reals and $m,n\in\mathbb{N}
$

Comment: Think counter example

Comment: I mean, if it's a prove, counterexample can't exist, can it?

Comment: Yes for this implication, so take the contrapositive form of this statement: if there's a counterexample, a proof can't exist.  Can you come up with one by substituting some values of $a$, $b$?

Comment: @AFalseName Well, find a counter example to $(a^m+b^m)^{n}= (a^n+b^n)^m$...

Comment: Of course it can. To disprove a statement, a counter example is excellent!

Comment: Are you trying to prove this is true for ALL $n,m\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: @mike for distinct $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Are you asking to show that the equation doesn't hold for any $a,b,m,n$ satisfying the conditions?

Comment: Are $a$ or $b$ allowed to be zero?

Comment: i goofed up. We need to show that if $$(a^m+b^m)^{n}= (a^n+b^n)^m$$ then m=n

Comment: If $m$ and $n$ are odd the pair $(a,-a)$ will be a counterexample. Probably the restriction $a>0$, $b>0$ will help.

Comment: @user added a,b are fixed reals

Comment: If you fix $b=-a$ it fails.

Comment: ok, will add that condition too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factorizing by $a$ you obtain:
$$\left(1+\left(\frac{a}{b} \right)^n \right)^{m}=\left(1+\left(\frac{a}{b} \right)^m \right)^{n}$$
with $x=\left(\frac{a}{b} \right)^n$ this is the same as:
$$\left(1+x \right)^{m}=\left(1+x^\frac{m}{n}\right)^{n}$$
i.e
$$\left(1+x \right)^\frac{m}{n}=\left(1+x^\frac{m}{n}\right)$$
so this is the same as showing that if it exists $x>0$ such that:
$$(1+x)^\gamma=(1+x^\gamma)$$ then $\gamma=1$.

---

Let $f(x)=(1+x)^\gamma-(1+x^\gamma)$

Then if $\gamma \neq 1$
$$f'(x)=\gamma \left((1+x)^{\gamma-1}- x^{\gamma-1}\right)$$
so if $\gamma >1$ the function is strictly increasing and if $\gamma<1$ strictly decreasing. In both cases as $f(0)=0$ there is no $x>0$ such that $f(x)=0$.

So $\gamma=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Counter example:

Take $a = b = m = 1$ and $n = 2$

Then

LHS is $4$ and RHS is $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: take $m=2,n=3$ then we get
$$(a^2+b^2)^3={a}^{6}+3\,{a}^{4}{b}^{2}+3\,{a}^{2}{b}^{4}+{b}^{6}$$
$$(a^3+b^3)^2=a^6+2a^3b^3+b^6$$

Comment: I tried using binomial and simplified it to proving $$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nk(\frac ab)^{mk} \ne \sum_{k=1}^m\binom mk(\frac ab)^{nk}$$